# Using JNDI to share objects beetween differends Java programs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, serializable, apache-tomee

I'm trying to run the following example but I did not succeed.

The intention is sharing objects through JNDI between two Java programs running on different virtual machines. I'm using TomEE 1.5.1 and TomEE 1.6

The JNDI parameters that I'm using are:

```
Hashtable<String, String> ctxProps = new Hashtable<String, String>();
ctxProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
ctxProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http://myjndihost.com:8080/tomee/ejb");
ctxProps.put("java.naming.security.principal", "tomee");
ctxProps.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "tomee");
```

The Sharing class provide 3 methods: connect (called within the constructor), set and get, and It's source code is here:

```
public class Sharing
{
    private Context context=null;

    public Sharing() throws Exception
    {
        connect();
    }

    private void connect() throws Exception
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> ctxProps = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        ctxProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
        ctxProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http://localhost:8080/tomee/ejb");
        ctxProps.put("java.naming.security.principal", "tomee");
        ctxProps.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "tomee");

        context=new InitialContext(ctxProps);
        context=context.createSubcontext("DEMO");
    }

    public void set(String key, Serializable value) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            context.bind(key,value);    
        }
        catch(NameAlreadyBoundException ex)
        {
            context.rebind(key,value);
        }
    }

    public Object get(String key) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            return context.lookup(key);
        }
        catch(NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I run this TestSet.java

```
public class TestSet
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Sharing share = new Sharing();
        share.put("fecha", new Date());
    }
}
```

It's throught an javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException
    at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.createSubcontext(JNDIContext.java:551)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:483)
    at demo.Sharing.connect(Sharing.java:32)
    at demo.Sharing.<init>(Sharing.java:20)
    at demo.TestSet.main(TestSet.java:9)
```

But, if I remove the createSubcontect call (in line 32 of Sharing.java) then, the next exception is in the line 39, when
try to bind an object.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException
    at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.bind(JNDIContext.java:511)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
    at demo.Sharing.put(Sharing.java:39)
    at demo.TestSet.main(TestSet.java:10)
```

Of course, next step will be run TestGet.java but the time has not arrived because 
I could not run succefully TestSet yet.

The original example is taken from here, using WebLogic.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076440/jndi/use-jndi-to-share-objects-between-different-virtual-machines.html

Thanks a lot.
Pablo.

Comment: OpenEJB is trying to tell you "the JNDI context is read-only for you, client application".

Comment: Unlike other containers, e.g. JBoss, the InitialContext implementation of Tomcat is [read-only](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).

Comment: So, if I use JBoss instead OpenEJB this this example must run fine? Do you know any way to avoid this "read-only" feature in OpenEJB? Thanks!

Comment: You're right, it works perfectly with JBoss. Thank you very much!